# OpenGL unable to sync "player" FPS to monitor refresh rate

Tags: opengl, video-processing, glfw

I am trying to write a video player that will play at the the EXACT FPS as the monitor refresh rate (lets say it is 60Hz).
I am writing c++ (VS2010) on windows and using OpenGL.
I have a very strong PC, when no sync is set I can reach to 500FPS.

### this is the relevant code:

```
   glfwSwapInterval(1);
   while (1)
   {
     glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,Texture[frameIndexInArray]);
     glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
     glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        ...
     glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
     glEnd();
     glFinish();
     glfwSwapBuffers(window);
     glfwPollEvents();
        ...
   }
```

---

the vertical sync option on the graphics driver set to "on".
and I have a grabber that records my output via DP cable. (I know for a fact that it works fine)

my problem is that my player, once in a few hundreds frames is getting out of sync,
the output is: frame(n-1), frame(n), frame(n), frame(n+1) ... (double frame)
or it can also be: frame(n-1), frame(n), frame(n), frame(n+2) ... (double and skip frame)

I tried to use glfwSwapInterval (0) and to set vsync in the graphics driver to "application settings", I tried without glFinish(), I even tried to give the thread high priority with SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL);

is it possible to get exactly 60FPS? end if so, how?? I could use any advice you have 'cause I literally tried everything I know.

Comment: Calling `glFinish (...)` before the swap is likely to increase the odds that you will swap your buffers too late to meet the VSYNC deadline. It will only exacerbate your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for some reason you are ever late on a buffer swap, you will wind up drawing 1 frame for at least two monitor refreshes while VSYNC is enabled.

If your driver supports adaptive VSYNC (most NV and AMD drivers do), I would suggest trying that first. That way it will never draw faster than 60 FPS, but if you are slightly late it is not going to penalize you. Check for this `WGL` extension: [`WGL_EXT_swap_control_tear`](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/opengl/specs/WGL_EXT_swap_control_tear.txt) and if it is supported, you can pass **-1** to `glfwSwapInterval (...)`. The extension does not add any new functions, it just gives meaning to negative values for the swap interval.

GLFW may be too stupid to accept a negative value (I have never tried it), and you might have to interface directly with the platform-specific function: `wglSwapIntervalEXT (...)`

Comment: I had an integrated GPU in my PC, I switched to a new PC with AMD graphics card and it looks like it's working fine now, thanks